# Angular $http PUT - Apache returned 401 error on PUT

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I'm using this Angular code to send CORS HTTP PUT request:

```
return $http.put(path, params).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

In my Apache2 logs I see the following error:

```
10.0.8.204 - - [05/Apr/2016:13:12:56 +0000] "OPTIONS /users/1459774400684 HTTP/1.1" 401 387 "https://my.domain.com OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
```

which return 401 error.

I have an .htaccess file in my root directory stating (mod_header is enabled):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"

</IfModule>
```

I don't understand why or where can I learn more details about this error, since the error.log has nothing in it regarding this...

Comment: These headers worked for me: `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` AND 
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"` AND 
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, content-type, accept, origin, authorization, x-csrftoken"`

Comment: @AlonEitan it doesn't work..